# Custom NavHostFragment replace framelayout with viewgorup

Tags: android, navigation

There are some views and one `FrameLayout` in the layout. I want to custom `NavHostFragment` replace `FrameLayout` with `RelativeLayout`, it works but the views hierarchy is wrong. The ImageView should be top, but it is in the bottom.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/lb_nav_host_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/logo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my custom `NavHostFragment`:

```
public abstract class BaseModuleFragment extends NavHostFragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = null;
        if (getContentViewId() > 0) {
            view = inflater.inflate(getContentViewId(), container, false);
            View frameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.lb_nav_host_container);
            if (!(frameLayout instanceof FrameLayout)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("frame layout must exist");
            }
            frameLayout.setId(getId());
        } else {
            view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Was the method wrong, or how to solve?

Comment: I want to make `ImageView` overlay the `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout to this one. It should be ok

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivTop"
        android:id="@id/lb_nav_host_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/logo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, it can't work. Let me explain, normally `ImageView` will cover `FrameLayout`, but `FrameLayout` cover `ImageView`. I want to make `ImageView` overlay the `FrameLayout`

Comment: Can you post the picture described what you did?

Comment: please take a look at the two picture, one is wrong and another is right.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62302919/12717150, I use `Fragment#replace` to show what I mean. Can u give a help?

Comment: Show me the code when you replace FrameLayout with RelativeLayout

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62322944/12717150, just change the layout view level

Answer (score 0):

These pictures show:

- Wrong:
  [FrameLayout cover ImageView, it is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkedX.png)
- Right
  [ImageView should be top, this is right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIpMT.png)

Answer (score 0):

- `FrameLayout top`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/logo" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/lb_nav_host_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

- `ImageView top`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/lb_nav_host_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/logo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```